# C# get file Path from a file while windows forms app webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

im building a application for a private project im developing. So im building a file explorer with windows forms app, to display the filesystem i am using the WebBrowser and hardcoded the path from where it starts to display the files in a specific directory.

Now my idea was to display the owner of the file by single clicking on a file. But the problem is there is no event that is handling the single click event, for the specific case i am using.

Already know how to display owner and so on, but only with hardcoded path. I need the path by a single click for a file in the webBrowser.

Anyone got some idead how to realize something like that?

[That's how it looks this far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzG6a.png)

Comment: Do you want to get click event in WebBrowser?

Comment: Yea something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create class inherits from `WebBrowser` and you can override events' methods

And you can override any event you want

Use this code:

```cs
public class SuperWebBrowser : WebBrowser // Inherit
{
    public event EventHandler Click; // Event

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) // Fire event
    {
        EventHandler handler = Click;
        handler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```